# MonoTouch: Symbolicate Crash

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, symbolicate

I use Monotouch so don't get many crashes. But I got my first. I have opened the crash file in Xcode and it was symbolicated.

Is the following all I get in crash information? (looks like a problem in ctor)

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3640432c 0x363f3000 + 70444
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x332cdf54 0x33280000 + 319316
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x332c6fe4 0x33280000 + 290788
3   Nations                     0x005107f0 mono_handle_native_sigsegv (mini-exceptions.c:2249)
4   Nations                     0x00539680 sigabrt_signal_handler (mini-posix.c:196)
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x332d8532 0x33280000 + 361778
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x332cdf54 0x33280000 + 319316
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x332c6fe4 0x33280000 + 290788
8   Nations                     0x0065f91c monoeg_g_logv (goutput.c:135)
9   Nations                     0x0065f9f0 monoeg_assertion_message (goutput.c:155)
10  Nations                     0x004f18dc mono_thread_abort (mini.c:2639)
11  Nations                     0x0050f730 mono_handle_exception_internal (mini-exceptions.c:1536)
12  Nations                     0x005100d4 mono_handle_exception (mini-exceptions.c:1831)
13  Nations                     0x0053743c mono_arm_throw_exception (exceptions-arm.c:158)
14  Nations                     0x00537534 mono_arm_throw_exception_by_token (exceptions-arm.c:169)
15  Nations                     0x00492538 throw_corlib_exception (mscorlib.dll.6.s:186564)
16  Nations                     0x0001946c General_BaseUIApplicationDelegate__ctor (Nations.exe.6.s:414)
17  Nations                     0x00018b24 General_AppDelegateIPhone__ctor (Nations.exe.6.s:11)
18  Nations                     0x00455894 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr (mscorlib.dll.6.s:152470)
19  Nations                     0x004f5b60 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5759)
20  Nations                     0x005ec590 mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2757)
21  Nations                     0x00680e98 monotouch_ctor_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:719)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks pretty usefully symbolicated (the lib system stuff is not, which makes me suspect you are using iOS 5.0.1 with Xcode 4.2 — there’s a bug there). I never see more than this with Objective-C.

So yeah, sure looks like it's pointing to your AppDelegateIPhone.

Comment: Any info on what the bug is (bug in Xcode?) and when it will be fixed or what forum thread or online bug repo tracks it? Thanks